# cordova 1.6.1 android Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'showWebPage' of undefined

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i just upgraded phonegap 1.4.1 to 1.6.1 and also upgraded the child browser from https://github.com/libbybaldwin/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser

and i have added this line in plugins.xml file

```
<plugin name="ChildBrowser" value="com.phonegap.plugins.ChildBrowser.ChildBrowser"/>
```

but when i calling this

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage( "http://google.com", {
        showLocationBar: true
    });
```

i am geting this error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'showWebPage' of undefined

Comment: Been having this same issue for a few days. Hope we can find a solution.

Comment: its working in device like samsung galaxy pop or similar type device but not working in HTC or GALAXY S II or Sony ericsson Experia

Comment: after updating cordova 1.7.0 and updated childbrowser code now its working

Comment: can you link the new childbrowser code?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the 1.4.1 vs 1.6.1:

Please be aware that my github repo of phonegap-plugins is what I "froze" in internet time to allow continued use of phonegap 1.4.1 with plugins from that era.

Moving forward to cordova 1.6.1+ you'll need to move on the the official unofficial plugins at

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

Note: These plugins may or may not be updated work with cordova 1.6.1. Please read their individual README's and the blog below from a phonegap engineer:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/04/migrating-your-phonegap-plugins-to.html

Summary: moving from 1.4.1 to 1.6.1+ and using phonegap plugins will require some vigilance as there were many changes internally between those two versions.

Comment: Even using the official unofficial plugin I receive the same error.

Comment: its working in device like samsung galaxy pop or similar type device but not working in HTC or GALAXY S II or Sony ericsson Experia

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this error by using this code:

```
try {
var cb = new ChildBrowser();
console.log(cb);
cb.showWebPage('http://www.google.com');
}catch (err){
console.log(err);
}
```

Although this caused another error:

[PhoneGap Build + Cordova + ChildBrowser Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308818/phonegap-build-cordova-childbrowser-error)

If you don't get any errors and this solution works - please let me know!

Comment: i am getting this error TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'exec'

Comment: Some with me :\
Are you using phonegap build or eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

Have been fighting this same error for some days now and found that you can not call the childBrowser right away from your index.html, likely because  the initialization of the childBrowser plugin takes some time to complete.

This solution works:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.console.log('Opening Childbrowser...');
    window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("http://www.google.com", { showLocationBar: true });
}, 3500);
```

In other words: you have to wait for the childBrowser object to become available, there are more elegant solutions thinkable of course.

DISCLAIMER: tested with the current 1.7.0rc1 Cordaova release, not sure if this works for 1.6.1 as well.

Comment: Even better, just make sure the Cordova environment has been initialized by waiting for the `deviceready` event, as documented:

    `document.addEventListener("deviceready", myInitFunc, false);`